# knex.js: combination of orWhere followed by multiple where

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql, knex.js

I am writing a query with knex.js and i got stuck with orWhere.

I need a query like this:

```
select 
    count(*) 
from 
    `Project` 
where 
    `Project`.`createdAt` >= '2019-11-12' 
and 
    `Project`.`createdAt` <= '2020-11-19' 
and 
    ((`Project`.`productType` = 1) 
or 
    (`Project`.`productType` = 2))
```

but for some reason this is what i am getting:

```
select 
    count(*) 
from 
    `Project` 
where 
    `Project`.`createdAt` >= '2019-11-12' 
and 
    `Project`.`createdAt` <= '2020-11-19' 
or 
    (`Project`.`productType` = 1) 
or 
    (`Project`.`productType` = 2)
```

Notice there are two '`or`'s  which i want `and` in the place of first `or`

this is the code:

```
 builder.count('*')
.from('Project')
.where('Project.createdAt', '>=', '2019-11-12')
.where('Project.createdAt', '<=', '2019-11-19')
.orWhere({'Project.productType': 1})
.orWhere({'Project.productType': 2})
```

would appreciate any help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I see, you can try that:

```js
//
 builder.count('*')
.from('Project')
.where('Project.createdAt', '>=', '2019-11-12')
.where('Project.createdAt', '<=', '2019-11-19')
.where(function () {
    this.orWhere({'Project.productType': 1}).orWhere({'Project.productType': 2})
});

// or use arrow function
 builder.count('*')
.from('Project')
.where('Project.createdAt', '>=', '2019-11-12')
.where('Project.createdAt', '<=', '2019-11-19')
.where((bd) => {
    bd.orWhere({'Project.productType': 1}).orWhere({'Project.productType': 2})
});
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Worked for me! Saved me some headaches, too.